# How to reduce indicator size in tapbar in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the below `TabBar` which looks like the below one:

[image]

and this is the below related code:

```
TabBar(
                onTap: (index) {
                  cubit.changeBottomNavIndex(index);
                },
                indicator: BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border.all(color: goldDefaultColor, width: 1),
                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                  color: Colors.grey[600],
                ),
                labelColor: goldDefaultColor,
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
                tabs: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      Tab(
                        text: 'Live',
                      ),
                      CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 5.0,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    text: 'Map',
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    text: 'Device',
                  ),
                ],
                controller: _tabController,
              ),
```

so how to reduce the width and the height to be wrapped by content as the below image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the `labelPadding` property of the `TabBar` but either setting it directly on this `TabBar`, or by updating the value of `TabBarTheme` used by the `Theme` of the application, there by changing the appearance in all `TabBar` widgets used in your application.

The default value for `labelPadding` in flutter is  `EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0);` and the image shown above would be smaller, perhaps  `EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 4.0);` adjust the value to your preferred size

Answer (score -1):

1. Reduce the height of tabbar by wrapping with Container and giving it height.
2. width can be reduced by giving labelpadding = EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.0)

Comment: please add more details, I have already tried this, and it's not possible to wrap the text with padding because it's a parameter for taps